# Find a column and a value from a schema scan all the table in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsql-package

I am trying to find a column (`ABC`) and it's value `1234` from a schema , basically i need to to check if **ABC** and a value from this column **1234** is present in any other table that is mapped to **ABC** , i tried to do a search the most efficient way but it is taking lot of time and not retrieving the desired result

i have tried 
https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/

but the query is not results at all it is running running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write the output to a file if you get buffer overflow on `set Serveroutput` otherwise this should do.Output will have all tables that has `'ABC'` column and respective count shows count of record with `ABC` column value as `1234`.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 100000
DECLARE 
lv_count number(10):=0;
l_str    varchar2 (1000);
BEGIN 
FOR V1 IN 
(select distinct table_name 
 from dba_tab_columns 
 where column_name = 'ABC')

 LOOP

  BEGIN 
    lv_query := ' select count(*) from '||v1.table_name||' where ABC =1234';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query INTO lv_count;
    dbms_output.put_line(v1.table_name||' --> '||lv_count);

    EXCEPTION 
       WHEN OTHERS THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('OTHERS EXCEPTION '||v1.table_name||' ERRCODE '||SQLERRM||' '||SUBSTR(SQLCODE,1,200));
    END; 

 END LOOP;

END;
```

To find all tables having column_name ABC, simple query as below should do.

```
select table_name 
     from dba_tab_columns 
     where column_name = UPPER('ABC');
```

PS: Metadata tables(dba_Tab_columns) stores column_name in upper case, to avoid any issues with case ,converting the case to upper for the literal.

Second query in PL/SQL block,

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 100000
    DECLARE 
    lv_count number(10):=0;
    l_str    varchar2 (1000);
    lv_col_name varchar2(255) :='ABC';

    BEGIN 
    FOR V1 IN 
    (select distinct table_name 
     from dba_tab_columns 
     where column_name = lv_col_name)

     LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(lv_col_name||' '||v1.table_name);    
     END LOOP;

    END;
```

Comment: it should be - all_tab_columns i have also updated it and tried same error

Comment: It depends on what permission you have, i have replaced dba_tab_columns with all_Tab_columns, lv_query variable wasn't declare. It runs error free , could you try now.

Comment: @rakesh - Could you upvote if this worked for you. It should be pretty quick i believe.

Comment: @VN'Corner - i have one more question if  i want to just search  ABC ?

Comment: Just remove the BEGIN..END block within the Loop and replace it with dbms_output.put_line(v1.table_name); This will print all tables having column_name ABC.Alternately select distinct table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'ABC' will return all tables with column name 'ABC' which is the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: @VN'Corner i have tried i am runinng into errors - can you pls post it ?

Comment: Thanks i know that query , but i wanted to run using the block query like reusable for future purpose...