# I want to do select <column_name> from <table_name> where column_name and table_name should be coming from cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to do select `column_name` from `table_name` where `column_name`.

`table_name` should be coming from cursor.

Query:

```
DECLARE
COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50); 
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100); 
schema_name VARCHAR(100); 
A VARCHAR(100); 
B VARCHAR(100); 

CURSOR col_cursor IS 
  select col.owner as schema_name, 
       col.table_name, 
       col.column_name 
  from sys.all_tab_columns col 
  inner join sys.all_tables t 
    on col.owner = t.owner and 
       col.table_name = t.table_name 
where col.owner = 'PIYUSH1910_BEFORE' 
AND
      DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER' 
AND
      DATA_PRECISION IS NULL 
AND
      col.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%ER%'; 

BEGIN
 OPEN col_cursor; 

 LOOP
  FETCH col_cursor INTO schema_name,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME; 
  EXIT WHEN col_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT '||COLUMN_NAME ||' INTO A from ' || Table_Name || 'WHERE'||COLUMN_NAME||'- TRUNC('||COLUMN_NAME||',2) > 0'; 

  dbms_output.Put_line(A); 

END LOOP; 
CLOSE col_cursor; 
END
```

But its throwing this error:

> Error report - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. ORA-06512: at line 29 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended *Cause: *Action:

Comment: Above code is giving error like below 

Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.  
ORA-06512: at line 29
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Could you check the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663260/find-a-column-and-a-value-from-a-schema-scan-all-the-table-in-oracle/61663782?noredirect=1#comment109076196_61663782

Answer (score 1):

`INTO` clause must be at the end while using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT '||COLUMN_NAME ||' from ' 
        || Table_Name || ' WHERE '||COLUMN_NAME||'- TRUNC('||COLUMN_NAME||',2) > 0' 
        INTO A;
```

Also, space before and after `WHERE` keyword is added in the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT '|| COLUMN_NAME || ' from ' || Table_Name || 
                  ' WHERE ' || COLUMN_NAME || '- TRUNC('||COLUMN_NAME||',2) > 0'
  INTO A;
```

This moves the `INTO` clause to the correct position (in this case it's part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` rather than being part of the `SELECT`) and reformats the code slightly so that column names are separated from e.g. the `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: I think you're reading that wrong. When the string substitutions are made it would produce `SELECT SOME_COL from SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COL - TRUNC(SOME_COL, 2) > 0`. The assumption is that `SOME_COL` is a numeric column - but there's certainly no arithmetic being performed on the name of the column.

Comment: Jarvis - indeed.  Sign me -- "Embarrased".

Comment: De nada. It's Friday and we're all sitting at home in our underwear. ??? What do you mean, "Too Much Information"? :-)